# To do an estimation about a function with Lipschitz condition

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Lipschitz Condition** A function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition iff $\exists L>0,$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<L|x-y|, \forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$

Here is the problem. The origin problem in my assignment list is actually too complicated to state, so I have transformed the origin one to this:

**Problem** Let $f$ be a function satisfying a Lipschitz condition on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $v$, $v'$ are distinct points on $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfying $|v|=|v'|=1$. Determine whether
$$\left|\frac{f(tv)-f(tv')}{t}\right|\leqslant\sqrt{2}|f(v)-f(v')|, \forall t\ne 0$$
holds and give explanations either way.

Furthermore, does the result remain true in $\mathbb{R}^n$(just change '$\sqrt{2}$' to '$\sqrt{n}$')?

Comment: If you expect people to put in the effort to answer a question, then it is polite to put in some effort yourself. For example, simply telling us where you got the problem from or explaining what you tried would be a big step forward! (For further feedback/help with asking questions, you can ask [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback).)

Comment: @user1729, thanks for your reminding! The origin problem is  much more complicated and I have simplified to the presented edition.